# How do I consolidate case when statements that have (SUM)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to consolidate this query....

```
select substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) Article_Type,
    case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) like 'A%' then 'Accessories'
         else
         case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L02' then 'Spirit'
              else
              case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L03' then 'Wine'
                   else
                   case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L04' then 'Beer & Soft Drinks'
                        else
                        case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L05' then 'Confectionary'
                             else
                             case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L06' then 'Food'
                                  else
                                  case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) like 'P%' then 'Parfum/Cosmetics'
                                       else
                                       case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) like 'T%' then 'Tester'
                                            else
                                            case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) like 'X%' then 'GWP'
                                                 else
                                                 case when substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) like 'Z%' then 'Procurement'
                                                      else ''
                                                 end
                                            end
                                       end
                                  end
                             end
                        end
                   end
              end
         end
    end as "Translation",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) < 90 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "Less than 90",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) between 91
     and 120 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "91-120",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) between 121
     and 180 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "121-180",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) between 181
     and 360 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "181-360",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) between 361
     and 500 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "361-500",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) between 501
     and 900 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "501-900",
    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) > 900 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
         else ''
    end as "900+"
   from prtmst,
    invdtl
  where invdtl.prtnum = prtmst.prtnum
and prtmst.prt_client_id = 'HUS'
and prtmst.wh_id_tmpl = 'MFTZ'
and prtmst.typcod is not null
and invdtl.prt_client_id = 'HUS'
and invdtl.ship_line_id is null
and invdtl.wrkref is null
and invdtl.lst_arecod not in ('ADJS', 'CADJ', 'SADJ')
  group by substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3),
    to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  order by substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) asc
```

The problem that I have is that the result shows like this: (413 rows)

```
article_type    translation less than 90    91-120  121-180 181-360 361-500 501-900 900+
A71 Accessories         481             
L02 Spirit  1296                        
L02 Spirit  6                       
L02 Spirit          96              
L02 Spirit          60              
L02 Spirit          2100                
L02 Spirit          1014                
L02 Spirit  252                     
L02 Spirit  318                     
L02 Spirit      36                  
L02 Spirit          192             
L02 Spirit  1848                        
L02 Spirit  2124                        
L02 Spirit  1550                        
L02 Spirit  7547                        
L02 Spirit  4206                        
L03 Wine            96              
L03 Wine            417             
L03 Wine            258             
L03 Wine    492                     
L03 Wine    348                     
L03 Wine        448                 
L03 Wine    552                     
L03 Wine    60                      
L04 Beer & Soft Drinks  1416                        
L05 Confectionary                   19      
L05 Confectionary                   45      
L05 Confectionary           108             
L05 Confectionary               546         
L05 Confectionary           1112
```

I want the results to look like this: (11 Rows)

```
    translation less than 90    91-120  121-180 181-360 361-500 501-900 900+
A71             481             
L02     19147   36  3462                
L03     1452    448 771             
L04     1416                        
L05     3666    2153    3630    2691    387 1689    
P81     11460   7056    13581   19070   27626   12141   
P83                 525 344 253 
T85     880 802 2888    3811    4732    2539    
T90                 20  786 36  
X       5082                    6   
Z10             250 130     549
```

Please help me.... Basically the query is not grouping the case when statements because they have the sum function....therefore, is showing multiple results to be consolidated in the same column...

Comment: The whole point of a `CASE` expression is that you can put more than one condition in it: `CASE WHEN condition1 THEN value1 WHEN condition2 THEN value2 WHEN......... WHEN conditionN THEN valueN ELSE valueN+1 END`. No need to use `CASE WHEN ...ELSE CASE WHEN ELSE CASE WHEN`

Comment: Thank you Lamak..I nested the 'case when' to work as a vlookup function for article types....but the problem I believe is with  these statements:    case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) < 90 then sum(invdtl.untqty)
             else ''
        end as "Less than 90", because I had to use the (SUM) they are not being grouped in the (group by) statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the sum() function to the whole case expression and you can avoid a whole lot of repetition if you apply the datediff and substr functions in derived tables.

So after tweaking your original query a bit we get this query that should do what you want:

```
select 
    Article_Type,
    case left(article_type, 1)
        when 'A' then 'Accessories'
        when 'L' then 
           case Article_Type
               when 'L02' then 'Spirit'
               when 'L03' then 'Wine'
               when 'L04' then 'Beer & Soft Drinks'
               when 'L05' then 'Confectionary'
               when 'L06' then 'Food'
           end
        when 'P' then 'Parfum/Cosmetics'
        when 'T' then 'Tester'
        when 'X' then 'GWP'
        when 'Z' then 'Procurement'
        else ''
    end as "Translation",
    sum(case when diff < 90 then invdtl.untqty end) as "Less than 90",
    sum(case when diff between 91  and 120 then invdtl.untqty end) as "91-120",
    sum(case when diff between 121 and 180 then invdtl.untqty end) as "121-180",
    sum(case when diff between 181 and 360 then invdtl.untqty end) as "181-360",
    sum(case when diff between 361 and 500 then invdtl.untqty end) as "361-500",
    sum(case when diff between 501 and 900 then invdtl.untqty end) as "501-900",
    sum(case when diff > 900 then invdtl.untqty end) as "900+"
from (
    select substr(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) Article_Type, *
    from prtmst
) prtmst
join (
    select datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) diff, * 
    from invdtl
) invdtl on invdtl.prtnum = prtmst.prtnum
where prtmst.prt_client_id = 'HUS'
  and prtmst.wh_id_tmpl = 'MFTZ'
  and prtmst.typcod is not null
  and invdtl.prt_client_id = 'HUS'
  and invdtl.ship_line_id is null
  and invdtl.wrkref is null
  and invdtl.lst_arecod not in ('ADJS', 'CADJ', 'SADJ')
group by Article_Type
order by Article_Type asc
```

Comment: @UrielMunar Happy to have been of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to put your conditions inside your sum.  Change this:

```
case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) < 90 
     then sum(invdtl.untqty)
     else ''
end as "Less than 90"
```

to:

```
sum(
  case when datediff(day, to_char(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) < 90 
     then invdtl.untqty
     else 0
  end) 
as "Less than 90"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `SUM`over a `CASE` (and cleanup your "translation" CASE:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) Article_Type,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) LIKE 'A%' THEN 'Accessories'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L02'   THEN 'Spirit'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L03'   THEN 'Wine'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L04'   THEN 'Beer & Soft Drinks'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L05'   THEN 'Confectionary'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) = 'L06'   THEN 'Food'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) LIKE 'P%' THEN 'Parfum/Cosmetics'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) LIKE 'T%' THEN 'Tester'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) LIKE 'X%' THEN 'GWP'
         WHEN SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) LIKE 'Z%' THEN 'Procurement'
         ELSE ''
    END AS "Translation",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) < 90                THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "Less than 90",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) BETWEEN 91 AND 120  THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "91-120",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) BETWEEN 121 AND 180 THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "121-180",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) BETWEEN 181 AND 360 THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "181-360",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) BETWEEN 361 AND 500 THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "361-500",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) BETWEEN 501 AND 900 THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "501-900",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(DAY, TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), sysdate) > 900               THEN invdtl.untqty ELSE 0 END) AS "900+"
   FROM prtmst,
    invdtl
  WHERE invdtl.prtnum = prtmst.prtnum
AND prtmst.prt_client_id = 'HUS'
AND prtmst.wh_id_tmpl = 'MFTZ'
AND prtmst.typcod IS NOT NULL
AND invdtl.prt_client_id = 'HUS'
AND invdtl.ship_line_id IS NULL
AND invdtl.wrkref IS NULL
AND invdtl.lst_arecod NOT IN ('ADJS', 'CADJ', 'SADJ')
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3),
    TO_CHAR(invdtl.fifdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  ORDER BY SUBSTR(prtmst.typcod, 1, 3) ASC
```